# Fourier tricks for $f(x)=\sin(x)+x\cos(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

Let $f(x)=\sin(x)+x\cos(x)$, $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

- Find the Fourier series of $f$

---

I know all the formulas for the coefficients $a_0,b_0,c_0$ and $a_n,b_n,c_n$ and the property for odd functions that then $c_k(f)=c_{-k}(f)$ i.e $a_k(f)=0$ and that we can write it as a sine series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k(f)\sin(kx)$$

Is there a trick I am oveseeing as brute forcing it seems really tough and pages long?

Comment: Fourier series are also linear. The Fourier series for $f = g + h$ are the coefficients of $g$ plus the coefficients of $h$

Comment: It’s a little work. Ignore the $\sin x$ at first and use: $$\sin(kx)\cos(x)=\frac12\left(\sin((k+1)x)+\sin((k-1)x)\right)$$ then use integration by parts.

Comment: More generally, if $g(x)$ has Fourier coefficients $a_k,b_k$ then $g(x)\cos x$ has Fourier coefficients: $$a_k’=\frac12(a_{k-1}+a_{k+1}),  b_k’=\frac12(b_{k-1}+b_{k+1})$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh the generel for $g(x)$ is interesting. What are these for $g(x)\sin(x)$?

Comment: another observation. I got the fourier for $x\sin(x)$ - Couldn't I use that as the derivative of $x\sin(x)$ is $\sin(x)+x\cos(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

I will just show the FS for $x\cos(x)$. I will use the FS with complex coefficients $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$.
$$2\pi c_n=\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}x\cos(x)e^{-ixn}dx=\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}\frac{xe^{ix}+xe^{-ix}}{2}e^{-ixn}dx$$
$$\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}xe^{ix(1-n)}dx=i\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}x\sin(x(1-n))dx=2\pi i\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{(1-n)}$$
$$\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}xe^{-ix(n+1)}dx=-i\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}x\sin(x(n+1))dx=-2\pi i\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{(n+1)}$$
$\forall n \neq -1,1$, therefore
$$2\pi c_n=\pi i\bigg(\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{(1-n)}-\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{(n+1)}\bigg)$$
$$2\pi c_1=\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}\frac{xe^{ix}+xe^{-ix}}{2}e^{-ix}dx=\frac{i}{2}\pi$$
$$2\pi c_{-1}=\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}\frac{xe^{ix}+xe^{-ix}}{2}e^{ix}dx=-\frac{i}{2}\pi$$
Here is a truncated one:

[image]

Comment: So you to make sure do I not have to find $c_0,c_{-n},c_{n}$? I am not seeing how the written series would apear for this function would look with the coefficients given in the post. furthermore, if I now find it for $sin(x)$ is the complete FS just the sum of both FS's? And may I ask in what program you made the nice graph :)?

Comment: another observation. I got the fourier for $x\sin(x)$ - Couldn't I use that as the derivative of $x\sin(x)$ is $\sin(x)+x\cos(x)$?

Comment: $\cos\pi n=(-1)^n.$

Comment: @user879295 I used Python and coded everything myself.  The FS coefficients of a sum of functions is the sum of the FS coefficients of the respective functions.

Comment: So having the fourier of $f$ can not give the the fourier of $f'$?

Comment: @user879295 you should post another question about that